# Re-directing users other than the admin to the Home page after login

Tags: php, mysql

I made a query earlier about allowing the `admin.php` website to open up upon logging in as the administrator. It all works now, but when I try to Login as another user, it jumps straight to the invalid username and password page. Here is my database structure:

[image]

I entered some sample information to test the login system.
If the username: `admin` and password: `admin` gets typed it, it transfers to the `admin.php` page which is great.

If I try to enter the username: `Filip` and password: `Filip`, it just comes up with invalid details message.

I want it to transfer all remaining users to the home page which is `login_success.php`.

Here is the **PHP** code:

```
<?php

$hostname = 'hostname';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$con=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$myusername = $_POST['username'];
$mypassword = $_POST['password'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM Client_Information WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">'; 
    echo 'alert("' . $myusername . ' / ' . $mypassword . '")'; 
    echo '</script>'; 
}
    else {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $idClientValue = $row[0];
        if ($idClientValue == '47') {
            header("Location: admin.php");
        }
    }

if($count==1){
    $seconds = 5 + time();
    setcookie(loggedin, date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
    header("location: login_success.php");
}

else{
    echo '<div class="incorrect">- Incorrect username or password -</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: where is $count initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting invalid details  because you didn't defined the `$count` variable in your code.

**Modification Block:**

```
<?

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ( $count > 0 ) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $idClientValue = $row[0];
    // if user login is admin than redirect to admin.php
    if ($idClientValue == '47') {
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }
    else{
        // if not admin redirect login_success.php    
        $seconds = 5 + time();
        setcookie("loggedin", date("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
        header("location: login_success.php");
    }
}
else{
echo '<script language="javascript">'; 
        echo 'alert("' . $myusername . ' / ' . $mypassword . '")'; 
        echo '</script>'; 
}


?>
```

**Side Note:**

Always add `error_reporting` on in your code for development and staging not for production.

Please do not use `mysql_*` extension because its deprecated and not available in PHP 7. You can use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

If these are your production credentials, do not share anywhere.

Comment: Awesome that work great, thanks for the reply :) And side note taken into account :)

Comment: Actually, upon further checks, it allows everyone to login, but its supposed to only allow people on a database to login

Comment: @filip accept the answer this will help  to other who also facing the same issue

Comment: Yes I did. Is there any site we can talk on to sort out my issue? I would be very very grateful as this is extremely important to me! @devpro

Comment: I added you but no confimation @devpro :P

Comment: @filip SO is the best way to share your programming issues. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be checking only Username.

If username not exists then show incorrect username / password

if username exists, then in side that condition add one more if condition to check password

if password matches then add check user role if its admin then redirect to admin otherwise login_success

if password not matched, then show incorrect username / password

Comment: Do you mind providing the code for that? It will give me something to study visually :)

Comment: send a contact request at www.naveedramzan.com

Answer (score 0):

You can add one field call `user_role` and assign roles to users instead of using static primary id.

for ex:

```
id   username   role
1    admin      admin
2    filip      normal
3    xyz        normal
```

So check if logged in user role is "admin" instead of id to redirect admin users to "admin.php" and others to "login_success.php".